# How to upload a folder into public storage on Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I was trying to input and store a folder(containing several files) into my local directory but
I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my input form:

```
<input type="file" name="folder" id="folder" multiple webkitdirectory directory>
```

Here is what's in my controller:

```
  if($request->folder){
        foreach($request->folder as $folder){
            $up_location='image/converter/';
            $name_gen = $folder->getClientOriginalName();
            $folder->move($up_location,$name_gen);
        }}
```

I have no issues uploading multiple files but uploading a folder(and keeping the folder structure the same) seem to not work.

[I placed dd($request->all() in my controller after the form inputs and it seems that I got a .tmp file even though I gave a folder containing a few .png files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MqZ0.png)

Comment: try add `dd($request->all())` and see what you have. Maybe you need send array? like `name="folder[]"`?

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin Hi, I edited in the results. As for sending in an array, doesn't it only work for multiple files? I would like the whole folder to be uploaded, not just the files inside it.

Answer (score -1):

> It's image upload example.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class FileUploadController extends BaseController
{
    public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        $user = (object) ['image' => ""];

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $original_filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $original_filename_arr = explode('.', $original_filename);
            $file_ext = end($original_filename_arr);
            $destination_path = './upload/image/';
            $image = 'ME-' . time() . '.' . $file_ext;

            if ($request->file('image')->move($destination_path, $image)) {
                $user->image = '/upload/image/' . $image;
                return $this->responseRequestSuccess($user);
            } else {
                return $this->responseRequestError('Cannot upload file');
            }
        } else {
            return $this->responseRequestError('File not found');
        }
    }

    protected function responseRequestSuccess($ret)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $ret], 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }

    protected function responseRequestError($message = 'Bad request', $statusCode = 500)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'error' => $message], $statusCode)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```